# Paging query with NodeJS and ObjectionJs

Tags: node.js, objection.js

Hi I am relatively new to NodeJS and am using [ObjectionJS](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js) as ORM.
I want to do a migration script for my users table, in order to change some field of each row.

I make something like this

```
export default class UserMigration {

  constructor(firstId, lastId = 9000000) {
    this.firstId = firstId;
    this.lastId  = lastId;
  }

  migrate() {
    let more = true;
    let page = 0;
    let batchSize = 100;
    while(more) {
      UserModel.query().where('id', '>=', this.firstId)
        .where('id', '<=', this.lastId)
        .page(page, batchSize)
        .then((result) => {
          let users = result.results;
          debug('Page: ', page);
          debug('PageSize: ', users.length)
          users.forEach((user) => {
            // Do something here
          });
          if(result.results.length < batchSize) {
            more = false
          } else {
            page++;
          }
        })
    }
  }

}
```

But then I realize that the query is being executed asynchronously while the `while` block is being executed synchronously, is that correct?

How can I achieve the migration without making one big query that returns all the users at once?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved that using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```
export default class UserMigration {

  constructor(firstId, lastId = 9000000) {
    this.firstId = firstId;
    this.lastId  = lastId;
  }

  run() {
    this.migrateV3().then((data) => {
      debug('All migrated');
      debug('data: ', data);
    }).catch((data) => {
      debug('Error');
      debug('data: ', data);
    });
  }

  async migrateV3() {
    let more = true;
    let page = 0;
    let batchSize = 100;
    while(more) {
      try {
        let result = await UserModel.query().where('id', '>=', this.firstId)
          .where('id', '<=', this.lastId)
          .page(page, batchSize);
        let users = result.results;
        debug('Page: ', page);
        debug('PageSize: ', users.length)
        for(let user of users) {
          debug(`User ${user.id} migration start`);
          // Do something
        };
        if(result.results.length < batchSize) {
          more = false
        } else {
          page++;
        }
      }
      catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }
}
```